Unreal Engine : I can't fix "Interfaces with BlueprintCallable functions but no events should explicitly declare NotBlueprintable on the interface."
I'm working on an Unreal Engine project where I want to use C++ classes in Blueprint, and I have a problem with one of my interfaces.
Here is my "FBloc" Interface :
UINTERFACE(BlueprintType)
class UFBloc : public UInterface {
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    UFBloc() {}
    ~UFBloc() {}
};

class IFBloc {
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    TScriptInterface<UFBloc> next;

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
    virtual void Execute() const = 0;
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
    virtual void Update() const = 0;

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
    virtual TScriptInterface<UFBloc> GetNextNode() const { return next.GetObject(); }
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
    virtual void setNext(TScriptInterface<UFBloc>newNext) {next = newNext;}

    // UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
    // void DoSomething();
    
};

This class works well, my only problem is that it creates this Warning :
Warning: Interfaces with BlueprintCallable functions but no events should explicitly declare NotBlueprintable on the interface.
To fix it, I can add "NotBlueprintable" to my class, but I don't want to, because I won't be able to use my interface in BluePrint.
The other solution is to add an "event" to my function, but the warning stays even if I add this :
UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
void DoSomething();

How can I remove the warning and still use my interface with BluePrint ?

You can still call your functions in blueprint when you mark the interface with UINTERFACE(BlueprintType, NotBlueprintable), as long as you mark the function with UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable).
NotBlueprintable Only means that you can't implement the functions in blueprint. So you can't mark any function with BlueprintNativeEvent or BlueprintImplementableEvent.
If you want to have functions that can be implement in C++ and Blueprint, you have to use BlueprintNativeEvent. Then you can't mark the function virtual and have to implement it in C++ with an additional _Implementation suffix
UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
void DoSomething_Implementation();

To call this function in C++, you have to use a generated static function like
IFBloc::Execute_DoSomething(<object that implements IFBloc>)

See: https://dev.epicgames.com/documentation/en-us/unreal-engine/interfaces-in-unreal-engine?application_version=5.5
